# Is there a way to disallow domains in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way to pass a list to scrapy to tell it what domains it can't visit?

Kind of like the opposite of allowed_domains = ['google.com']

I am trying to do broader crawls but am getting hung up in big domains with thousands of pages containing irrelevant information.

My target is too broad to list everything in 'allowed_domains', I just want to exclude a list of sites that I choose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do what you want.

The easiest way to achieve this would probably be replacing scrapy's [OffsiteMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite) with a custom one.
Something as simple as overwriting the [`should_follow()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py#L45) method might be all you need.